# User Account Picture doesn't display on Remote Desktop prompt

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, active-directory

In an Active Directory Domain, I'm logging on via Remote Desktop to various AD clients.

In Windows 7, the Remote Desktop connection prompt displays the last username I used to connect to the client I've selected.  But, this last username never has the correct picture.  It always has the default user (`%ProgramData%\Microsoft\User Account Pictures\user.bmp`, the "sunflower" on most computers) picture.

I thought that setting the [User Account Picture on a domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/165418/login-user-picture-on-domain) rather than just setting the User Account Picture in the per-computer profile would solve this, but nothing has changed.

I know this works outside of the Domain, since I connect to other machines as well, and see the proper User Account Pictures (User Icons) for those non-Domain users.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

RDP uses the account image from the local PC being used for RDP login when it exists on both the client computer, and the host.  After login, it will display the host user account image at the top of the RDP session's Start menu if it is different.

If the user's domain account doesn't exist on the local PC you are RDP'ing from, with an image set, but it does on the host with an image set, RDP will display the default sunflower. After login, it will display the host user account image at the top of the RDP session's Start menu.